# How to set the text of a submit button using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

For some reason `$("#thebutton").val("New text")` doesn't work.

Comment: Can you show us the HTML for the button?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Well, this works for me (tested on Chrome 4, FireFox 3.6, IE8):

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("#thebutton").val("New text");
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input id="thebutton" type="submit" value="OK" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: $("#thebutton").prop("value", "New text"); instead of the one above.. (newer jquery afaik)

Answer (score 7):

If you are using html button i.e. `<button id='thebutton ' > Button Val </button>` 
then use `$("#thebutton").text("NEW Text");`