# How to set the text of a button using JScript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I'm trying to set the text on a button in a JScript function. I am using a JScript function like this...

```
    function myfunction(sender, eventArgs)
    {
        wanted_text = window.source_text_field.get_displayText();

        if (document.getElementById("my_span_element") != null)
        {
            document.getElementById("my_span_element").innerText = wanted_text;
        }

        if (document.getElementById("my_button") != null)
        {
            document.getElementById("my_button").text = wanted_text;
        }

    }
```

where the controls concerned are define like this...

```
    <span id="my_span_element" class="some_class"></span>

    <asp:Button id="my_button"
                runat="server"
                class="some_other_class"
                text=""
                Width="48"
                Height="25"
                onclick="do_foo"/>
```

The text in the span element is set correctly but the button is unaffected. I've also tried `innerText`, `Value`, `Text`, and also attempted to use the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2294881/how-to-set-the-text-of-a-submit-button-using-jquery) but to no avail.

Can anyone see what I have overlooked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 problems here:

First: you use wrong attribute - should be "value", instead of "text"

Second: `document.getElementById("my_button")` will not work because ASP.NET assigns it's own ids to controls. If you take a look at generated markup you will notice that id of the element is completely different.

If your javascript is inside of the same .aspx page as `<asp:button />` control, you can do like this:

```
document.getElementById("<%= my_button.ClientID %>").value = "some text";
```

Answer (score 6):

Change the `.value` attribute of button:

```
document.getElementById("my_button").value = "new value";
```

Answer (score 3):

ASP.Net generates its own IDs for server controls.

You need to write `<%= my_button.ClientID %>` to get this generated ID.

Comment: SLaks is right. When you use asp.net tags like asp:Button, the server evaluates these tags and renders them properly before sending the final html to the browser. If you take a look at your source, you'll see an <input tag for your asp:Button with a prepended client side id something like ctl00_MasterPageBody_ctl01_my_button. Check out this link for more info: http://weblogs.asp.net/asptest/archive/2009/01/06/asp-net-4-0-clientid-overview.aspx